# Web Api Async call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a 404 error (not found) error when executing test from a console application calling Web Api 2 async service.  I am using EF 4.5.1 and MVC.  I have two identical controllers one async (see below) and the other not.

this call works: http://api.ptagis.org/tagdata/3D9.1C2D927A1B

this does not: http://api.ptagis.org/tagdataasync/3D9.1C2D927A1B

Here I am trying to test Web Api async service:

```
[Route("{tag}")]
public async Task<TaggingEvent> GetTaggingEventByTagAsync(string tag)
{
    TaggingEvent tagEvent = null;

    if (IsValidTagCode(tag))
    {

        tagEvent = await context.TaggingEvents.FindAsync(tag);

        if (tagEvent == null)
        {

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No tag found matching = {0}", tag)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Tag Code Not Found"
            };

            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Invalid tag code = {0}", tag)),
            ReasonPhrase = "Invalid PIT Tag Code Format"
        };

        throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
    }
    return tagEvent;                        
}
```

With this Console Application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();

    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {   

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.ptagis.org/");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("tagdataasync/3D9.1C2D927A1B");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                TaggingEvent tag = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TaggingEvent>();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", tag.Tag, tag.Species, tag.Run);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas/thoughts/suggestions?

thank you

More info: My route is: [RoutePrefix("tagdata")]

My code synchronous looks like this:

```
    [Route("{tag}")]
    public TaggingEvent GetTaggingEventByTag(string tag)
    {
        TaggingEvent tagEvent = null;

        if (IsValidTagCode(tag))
        {
            tagEvent = context.TaggingEvents.Find(tag);

            if (tagEvent == null)
            {

                var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No tag found matching = {0}", tag)),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Tag Code Not Found"
                };

                throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Invalid tag code = {0}", tag)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Invalid PIT Tag Code Format"
            };

            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }

        tracker.TrackPageView("GetTaggingEventByTag", "tagdata"); 
        return tagEvent;
    }
```

Comment: What's the code for your synchronous service? How are your routes set up?

Comment: Sounds more like a routing issue. What does the synchronous version look like?

Comment: My code synchronous looks liek this:

Comment: Do you have any RoutePrefix on the controller?

Comment: the prefix on sync is [RoutePrefix("tagdata")]
the prefix on async is [RoutePrefix("tagdataasync")]